# The server tag is not well formed - hyperlink templatefield

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>


                                                                   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Details.aspx?MstId={0}&SaleDate={1}",HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("MstId").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("SaleDate").ToString())) %>'Text="View Details" />
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using above code to Show detail and wanted to pass two parameters in query string. but it is giving error as server tag is not well formed

Comment: you are trying to pass comma separated value in  hyperlink URL. Don't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code the issue possible because there is not space between single quotes and attribute "Text". Try to add a space in front of attribute "Text".